Surrounding selection with two line breaks
Suppose I have this code:
foo { bar }

I would like to change this to:
foo {
  bar
}

What is the best way to do this?
I use Neovim and I know this can be achieved with nvim-surround by adding a custom type of surrounding which surrounds the selection with two line breaks. Then I could just select the part inside the braces by vi} or ysi} and apply this surrounding. I was just wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, given that this scenario seems not so uncommon.

Actually, with the original tpope/vim-surround, (assuming you're in the {), this is as simple as cS{{.
Quoting the documentation:
Change surroundings is *cs* .  It takes two arguments, a target like with
|ds|, and a replacement.  *cS* changes surroundings, placing the surrounded
text on its own line(s) like |yS|.  Details about the second argument can be
found below in |surround-replacements|.  Once again, examples are in order.

[…]

There is also *yS* and *ySS* which indent the surrounded text and place it
on a line of its own.


…This is one more reason I'm baffled that Neovim aficionados like to rewrite excellent plugins in Lua for the sake of using Lua. Maybe the rewrite can do this easily and I just don't know it?

Tested with nvim-surround and it works. I didn't know the capital S thing. Thanks!
